# Redirect to external Route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11, angular13

I am new to angular. And I am facing the issue to redirect to external route. I want to redirect from my angular app to other MVC application.
Like: **[www.abc.com/angularapp](http://www.abc.com/angularapp)** to **[www.abc.com/mvcapp](http://www.abc.com/mvcapp)**

Please help how to redirect to these kind of routes

Comment: use a simple link.

Answer (score 5):

It's funny that you've tagged this with so many angular tags. This is a vanilla html / javascript question. You can navigate in the html with an `<a></a>` tag.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><button>Click Me!</button></a>
```

or in javascript with `window.location.href`

```html
<button (click)="redirect()">Click Me!</button>
```

```js
redirect() {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this implementation

[angular router to external links](https://adrianfaciu.dev/posts/angular-router-external-links/)

Answer (score -2):

you can use the following

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><button>facebook</button></a>
```